# Why do i get this error when trying to run my Twitter weather bot

Tags: python, api, twitter, bots, openweathermap

```
def reply_to_tweet():
    print("retrieving and replying to tweets...")
    last_seen_tweet = read_last_seen(FILE_NAME)
    # mentions_timeline() returns a list of 20 most recent mentions
    mentions = api.mentions_timeline(last_seen_tweet, tweet_mode="extended")

    # reversing to read old tweets first
    for mention in reversed(mentions):
        print(str(mention.id) + " - " + mention.full_text)
        last_seen_tweet = mention.id
        store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, last_seen_tweet)
        if "#" in mention.full_text.lower():
            print("found #")

            location = get_location(mention.full_text)
            weather = get_weather(location)

            # responding to tweet mention
            api.update_status("@" + mention.user.screen_name + weather, mention.id)

def get_location(tweet):
    # takes tweet and returns only the substring attached to hashtag
    tweet_location = [i.strip("#") for i in tweet.split() if i.startswith("#")[0]]
    tweet_location += " today weather.com"
    return tweet_location

def get_weather(query):
    for url in search(query, stop=1):
        print("Results is " + url)

    #this code sends a request and reads the webpage enclsed to the request
    request = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})

    webpage = urlopen(request).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")

    try:
        title = soup.findAll("span", "today-daypart-title")[0].string 
        phrase = soup.findAll("span", "today-daypart-wxphrase")[0].string
    except IndexError as e:
        forecast = (" could not find the weather, check back later")
        print(e)
    else:
        forecast = (" forecast for " + title + " is " + phrase)
        print(forecast)

    return forecast

while True:
    reply_to_tweet()
    time.sleep(15)
```

I then call reply_to_tweet(), it searches and displays the tweet but when it tries the location i get:
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
I am fairly new to bots and api, i am using BeautifulSoup, googlesearch and tweepy

Comment: Would you please edit your post to include the code for `get_weather()` as well as `reply_to_tweet()`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting string slicing on a bool function `startswith()`, try removing `[0]` from  `tweet_location = [i.strip("#") for i in tweet.split() if i.startswith("#")[0]]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried what you suggested which came with a new error "TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes"

Comment: @J_Simm Try this instead. `tweet_location = [i.strip("#") for i in tweet.split() if i.startswith("#")][0]`

Comment: Thanks, this works which is annoying as it was just that little thing, however for some reason it will not get the weather, it does not pull an error it just says "list index out of range". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any thought on why there is this index error?

Comment: @J_Simm What exactly are you trying to extract by iterating on 'tweet_location'?

Comment: The 'tweet_location' is there to extract a # found in the tweet and strip it of the # so it is just the location, e.g. '#London' extracts to 'London'. This is working because it gives me the correct URL for the weather of the location, however it does not tweet the weather.